# Finding a system of linear equations where space of solutions is exactly the span of some vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've searched and stumbled upon some similar questions. However, in my question system is not specified to be homogenous. Therefore I am confused as to what will the solution look like. Here is the question:

Consider $a = (-1, 2, 1, 2) , b=  (4, -3, 8, 2) \text{ and } c = (1, 1, 1, -1)$ and their span $V$ in  $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Find a system of linear equations for which the space of solutions is exactly the subspace $V$.

I have, so far, tried solve as if we are looking for homogenous linear equations. That's why, i have used the vectors as rows and found the reduced row echelon form. From there I have reached a solution, yet i am pretty sure i don't understand the gist of the question.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such system consists of a single equation:$$43x+8y-25z+26t=0.$$Note that this is equivalent to $\bigl\langle(43,8,-25,26),(x,y,z,t)\bigr\rangle=0$. I got this vector $(43,8,-25,26)$ solving the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\langle(-1,2,1,2),(x,y,z,t)\bigr\rangle=0\\\langle(4,-3,8,2),(x,y,z,t)\bigr\rangle=0\\\langle(1,1,1,-1),(x,y,z,t)\bigr\rangle=0.\end{array}\right.$$Of course, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the usual dot product.

Comment: I've found that {(43/26, 8/26, -25/26, 1)} is a basis for Kernel of the corresponding matrix. However doesn't kernel only deal with homogenous equation? And how do we know that this is the space of solutions that is exactly equal to span(a,b,c)?

Comment: I verified that $$h (-1,2,1,2)+j (1,1,1,-1)+k (4,-3,8,2)=\\=(-h+j+4 k,2 h+j-3 k,h+j+8 k,2 h-j+2 k)$$ satisfies the equation of José.

Comment: @Polygebra So you got the same answer as me. The space of solutions contains $\operatorname{span}(\{a,b,c\})$. Could it be larger? No, because $\dim\mathbb{R}^4=4$ and so if the space of solutions was larger, that would mean that *every* vector of $\dim\mathbb{R}^4$ would be a solutution, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: Oh, i see it now. How can we be sure that this is exactly V?

Comment: @Polygebra Since $V=\operatorname{span}(\{a,b,c\})$, that's what I proved in my previous comment.